# On Call Payments

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, job-description, tech-support

We have just been asked to do on call at my workplace (voluntary) from 1800-0800 M-F and 24hrs on weekends. With a 'carrot' of £300 per week.

They aren't however paying us for any time spent if we're actually called out as the £300 'covers' it.

Normally when doing this I've been paid for the week and also paid for any hours worked.

I'm wondering if anyone knows the laws around this? Can they get away with not paying us for working due to the lump sum weekly?

Comment: are you a salaried employee?

Comment: Yes we're all salaried

Comment: Then i would assume this will not differ much from overtime situation, which doesn't have to be paid: https://www.gov.uk/overtime-your-rights#:~:text=Overtime%20pay,how%20they're%20worked%20out

Comment: If it’s truly voluntary, make sure there’s an opt out clause you can activate *after* you’ve started - £300 a week might sound like money for old rope, but I’ve done on-call shifts in the past where you get called 2 or 3 times every night for an hour or more each time. If your company has no history of on call you don’t know how busy you’ll end up being for your “carrot”, and you might end up wishing you could get a good night’s sleep instead…

Comment: 1800-0800 M-F ?

Comment: @LoremIpsum, "**1800-0800 M-F**" means "**6:00 PM to 8:00 AM from Monday to Friday**".

Comment: Just so I'm clear, I understand your description of on call time to mean that you are on call all of the time you are not at work. Is that the intention? Or do you sign up for some weeks, or shorter periods, when you are on call?

Comment: So you want to volunteer for £300 for 3 callouts of 2 hours each per night ? So that's 30 hours, very poor sleep and how long will you survive?

Comment: Your being paid less the minimum wage for almost 40 hours of being on call, that’s a horrible deal, probably should be closer to €300 a day. The whole idea would be to have a rotating personnel, each would cover 12-24 hours a week. Then €300 becomes more reasonable

Comment: @Job_September_2020 thanks, I just wish people would spell things out. I can't be the only one who fails to decode that stuff... I hope so at least. xD

Comment: Hi. Could you please make it explicit what you mean by "on call *at my workplace*"? They do not expect you to sleep at your workplace, do they? Are you allowed to go home but expected to run to your workplace in case of a call?

Comment: What is "on call"? How is it defined? In any professional setting, there is a reaction time to the call, a reaction time to try to assess the problem and a reaction time to an attempt to fix it. This might look like "Needs to be reachable within 10 minutes by company issued phone, needs to be at their desk logging in remotely no later than 20 minutes after receiving the call, needs to be able to be physically at work if neccessary no later than 1 hour after the initial call." If this is not defined, then it's all clueless people and it is not even worth the paper the contract is printed on.

Answer (score 7):

Update: An important note. In the UK for salaried employees for purpose of pay, on-call time would be considered no differently than any other form of work (over)time. While your contract will govern when and how can this be called into action, it must still follow all the requirements for work time, minimum pay, max worked hours and so on.

> I'm wondering if anyone knows the laws around this?

For salaried employees in the uk law of overtime is relatively simple for most cases and [gov.uk covers it very succinctly](https://www.gov.uk/overtime-your-rights#:%7E:text=Overtime%20pay,how%20they%27re%20worked%20out):

> Overview
> If you have normal working hours, overtime usually means any
> time you work beyond these hours.
>
> Normal working hours are the hours fixed by your employment contract.
>
> Overtime pay
> Employers do not have to pay workers for overtime.
> However, your average pay for the total hours you work must not fall
> below the National Minimum Wage.
>
> Your employment contract will usually include details of any overtime
> pay rates and how they’re worked out.

And on compulsory overtime:

> You only have to work overtime if your contract says so.
>
> Even if it does, by law, you cannot usually be forced to work more
> than an average of 48 hours per week. You can agree to work longer -
> but this agreement must be in writing and signed by you.

So what seems to be happening is they want to renegotiate the clause in the contract you have now. You can of course refuse, but that may have consequences, and that assumes that current arrangement is actually in your contract, and not just done out of say good will. Of course it can be part of contract by conduct, even if not written down, but that's where it gets complicated and out of scope for this forum.

So to answer in shorter form

> Can they get away with not paying us for working due to the lump sum weekly?

Generally yes, but check your contract.

Answer (score 2):

Any employer can "get away" with *offering* any conditions of employment for any compensation whatsoever. You then can "get away" with accepting or declining the contract.

A question often asked here is "Can my employer unilaterally change my employment conditions from [good old contract] to [bad new contract]?" Employers often present this situation as "same job, different conditions" when it is actually "You're fired... want a new job?"

So the answer to "can my employer change the job conditions?" is the same as the answer to "can my employer fire me?" This varies greatly depending on what country and state you work in, and that's why the question often asked here.

BUT - In your case your employer is not taking anything away from your current employment conditions at all. He is offering you additional work. You can decline without penalty or inconvenience, so it is extremely unlikely that any law can be found to control his offer.

£300 for 128 hours is £2.34/hour, just for keeping your phone on. As a wage this would be ridiculous, but as a premium it's not bad. I suggest that your acceptance depend entirely on how often you expect to be called.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your first sentence right. Surely, employment law limits what an employer can offer..or what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer by Tymoteusz Paul (which is a good answer)

I've done On-call at multiple companies (in NZ though, but the laws are similar)

There's 4 common Scenarios - and they do come down to what is in your contract:

1: No On-Call allowance - all time logged is at OT rates
2: A Nominal On-Call Allowance - All time logged is at OT Rates
3: A Flat On-Call Allowance - No Time is logged for OT
4: A generous On-Call Allowance that covers the first N hours of On-call, subsequent time is logged at OT rates

For scenario 3 (which it sounds like your company is offering) - I believe it is legal - they would say that this Allowance covers the inconvenience of being On-Call + an average of what the OT time would be. For example - if you say that you only log 1 hour of OT per week on-call, and that equates to $75, and the inconvenience fee is $150 - then most of the time, you are getting a good deal. Of course, the one week where it's crazy and you have logged 8 hours, you miss out.

It all depends on how busy it is likely to be.

Comment: (4) Setting an hourly rate for actually being called out, and the first hours coming out of your allowance, seems fair. So you get paid for the inconvenience that you need to stay close to a phone and sober while on-call, while paying full rate for actual call outs, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

Within broad parameters like working time regulations or minimum wage laws, it is perfectly lawful for your employer to ask for volunteers on the terms offered.

However if the availability is taken seriously (and not just on a best-effort basis), it seems like a completely implausible level of coverage, basically covering all time that you're not actually in work.

No drinking, no socialising away from home, no fixed plans like even a dentist appointment, maybe not even being able to shop without abandoning your trolley if you get a call. And of course, the risk of not being able to get a decent night's sleep.

I'd think carefully before accepting the money in question. If calls happen once a year and the response time is quite slack (say 90 mins or 2 hrs) then it might be a reasonable deal, but if they happen once a week or require abrupt attention within say 15 or 30 mins, then I would think very carefully and be inclined to reject the offer.

Your employer should also think carefully about how reliable the response is likely to be. Such a gruelling on-call schedule means that conscientious workers who make serious efforts to be available would struggle to cope, so they'll tend to get an adverse selection of non-conscientious volunteers who take the money but whose availability isn't appreciably different than if they weren't on call.